# Why does the windows command prompt read my password when I didn't give it the password for the MySQL user account?

Tags: mysql, windows, cygwin, backup

I was trying to create a backup file of a MySQL database with MySQL-dump and I was using the "^" command so that I could skip a line in the command prompt. When I mistakenly didn't type a space between the "-p" command to prompt for the user's password and the "^" command, the command prompt didn't ask for my password, but still succeeded in creating the backup file and storing it in the specified directory. You can see in the commands above that when there is a space between the "-p" command and the "^" command, the interface asks for my password and I have to give it or else it fails. Does anyone know why the command succeeds without me giving the command prompt my password when there is no space between the "-p" and "^"?

Here is the code:

```
C:\>mysqldump --user="username" -p^
More? database> 
C:\path_name\backup.sql
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be 
insecure.

C:\>mysqldump --user="username" -p ^
More? database> 
C:\path_name\backup.sql
Enter password: the_password
```

Comment: Are you sure that in the first case the output file contains a valid backup dump, and not, say, an error message?